# error when using nginx load-balancing with node.js

Tags: nginx, iptables, firewall, load-balancing

I have setup load-balancing with nginx on centos7. My nginx.conf looks fine to me:

```
upstream backend {
        server 192.168.55.10:3000;
        server 192.168.55.12:3000;
   }


    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
          proxy_pass          http://backend;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
          proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
...
```

Nginx lives on the 192.168.55.10. When I now turn off node on this server to test load-balancing, then I am not able to make any http requests. Here is the error from my nginx error log:

> 2018/05/02 06:44:30 [error] 32547#0: *217 connect() failed (113: No
>   route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx,
>   server: , request: "GET /poweredby.png HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://192.168.55.12:3000/poweredby.png", host: "api.somedomain.com",
>   referrer: "https://api.somedomain.com/api/test"

I am not too familiar with the settings on this server, however the hosting team has confirmed that both servers have no restrictions to communicate with each other. But obviously I am missing something.

**firewall-cmd --list-all-zones:**

```
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client http https
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp 8000/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Out of quirousity: Why do you need the 3000th port? Also it is not an error, but I'm highly against editing nginx.conf directly. I always add separate config files as webapplications. Thinking about your issue, I've come across something similar in the past.

Comment: I recommend checking your firewalld and it's rules. The `No route to host` error message is 99% network issue, not NginX. Make sure all the services are open on the required interfaces. If you are using IPTables (Why would do do that tho... ) then you have to debug that one.

Comment: What services should I check? I am new to this and would need help with some commands if you don't mind.

Comment: `firewall-cmd --list-all--zones`

Comment: Thanks @Bert. Please see edited question with the result from that command.

Comment: Can you confirm, you can ping the 2nd server from the 1st server? Both IP and domain name wise please.